# Implement Customizing records

Tags: architecture, database, database-design, ruby-on-rails

I have the following tables:

1. Organization.
2. Articles
3. Templates

Organization is the parent of both articles and templates.

On the articles index page, I display (by default) all templates for the organization.

Here's my problem. How do I add the ability to customize which templates are shown for each article?

I could create a ArticleTemplates table that has the following schema:

1. id
2. article_id
3. template_id
4. included_on_article (boolean field that indicates if the template should be included on the article)

But then I see problems with this:

1. Adding new records to ArticleTemplates seems clunky, as it would have to change every time a new template was added to the organization.
2. As every article usually will have all templates, there will be a lot of records in ArticleTemplates that are the same.

Any better solutions?

Comment: `As every article usually will have all templates, there will be a lot of records in ArticleTemplates that are the same.` -- Not true.  The combination of id, article_id and template_id should be unique for any given record.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, You are correct. I meant that it seems like a lot of duplication in the records, not that they are exactly the same.

Comment: It's a linking table, containing only ids.  I don't think you should be concerned about the number of records in it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, One of my problems is that there are lots of articles. If a user were to create a new template, I would have to create a new ArticleTemplate for each article (potentially thousands). Is there not a better way?

Comment: But that's the reason you do this in a linking table.  I know you called this table `ArticleTemplates`, but they're not really templates.  Each one of these records is probably only about 32 bytes in size, and databases can handle billions of records in each table.

Comment: define _better way_ - are you talking in terms of performance or efforts? Former is already clarified by @RobertHarvey and later doesn't seem complex either.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have boolean field in `ArticleTemplates` table for indicating if tempalte should be included to article.

Because you mentioned *As every article usually will have all templates* - you can create "aggregate" table which will contains only templates excluded from articles

```
ExcludedTemplates
    ArticleId
    TemplateId
```

In the application you will create a scope which load only article's templates which not exists in `ExcludedTemplates` table.

With this approach new template will be automatically included in all articles without creating thousands of new records.